# Change Help Center links to show their title

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, help-center

For example, if I paste the link `http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic` in a comment, change the anchor text to "Help Center: What topics can I ask about here?" I think this should be done the same way as when a link to a question is posted in a comment, question, or answer.

Comment: `I think this should be done the same way as when a link to a question is posted in a comment, question, or answer.` The behavior you describe here does not happen for comments, just questions and answers

Answer (score 1):

This is already available to a certain extent. All you have to do is append the last part of the URL to the magic `[help]` comment. The `[help]` comment is converted in to a "help center" link automatically.

So,

- `[help/asking]` → https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
- `[help/on-topic]` → https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- `[help/dont-ask]` → https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
- `[help/closed-questions]` → https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Obviously the comments are site aware, so if you make it on meta it'll point to the meta help center.

Comment: `[help/on-topic]` is converted to : [help/on-topic].

Comment: Your comment seems to be precisely why this fails to answer the question. He doesn't want it converted to "help center". That's ugly, non-descriptive, and grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, I think the anchor text needs to be specific for on-topic vs off-topic instead of both merely saying just "help center", and if I don't find a question about it here on MSE or MSO, I'm going to ask for that as a feature request.